# In ethereum private blockchain, how to get list of transactions of particular address?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, sendtransaction

I build own ethereum private blockchain.Generating address and assign to users.Now how I will get the transaction info If user make payment from any third party api to our generated address then how I will get the detail of transactions.

1) Please confirm me one thing from using any other third party API.User can make payment in our ethereum private blockchain address.

2) How do I get the transaction list of each address.

Answer (score 0):

User can make transaction to the blockchain using third party api. User needs to sign the transaction with his keystore. Then he can send it to the blockchain. Metamask you can use; which is a browser plugin. It can be connected to any node of the network. The user will provide the credentials of the keystore in this plugin and make transaction.

To get the list of addresses from which transaction has been issued, you need to iterate over the blockchain. Fetch each block and get the transaction hash list from the block. Then, get transaction receipt of the transactions using transaction hash. In the receipt you will find the from and to address of the transaction.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way. You can traverse all blocks, and check from or to address of every transaction.
You can try use [etherscan api](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-internal-transactions-by-address).
Or you can get every block from chain and store transactions by address.